# Distortion/signal noise in OpenCV frames server side through gRPC

Tags: image, api, opencv, raspberry-pi, grpc

I am trying to stream frames from a Raspberry Pi to a VCPU server. While I receive some of the frames intact, some of them seem to be affected by some weird distortion, while the others make it through without problem. I do not think this is a problem on the `RPi` since I can write the images on the `RPi` and they seem to be fine.

Distorted image:

[image: Distorted image]

Distorted somewhere in the RGB channels:

[image: Distorted somewhere in the RGB channels]

I also do not think there is anything inherently wrong with the gRPC side of communications since some of the frames make it through just fine, and I have also eliminated frame rate as an issue because I tried 1 fps or even 0.25 fps, and the problem still exists.

The code I am using server side is as follows:

```
class Greeter(imageTest_pb2_grpc.ImageTestServicer):
  def Analyse(self, request_iterator, context):
    for req in request_iterator:
        self.frame = np.array(list(req.img))
        self.frame = np.array(self.frame, dtype = np.uint8 )
        self.frame = self.frame.reshape( [480,640,3] )
        yield imageTest_pb2.MsgReply(reply = 1)
```

Comment: this needs debugging details. make the issue reproducible. narrow the space in which the problem occurs (reduce the code). review [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.